# php loop generates a 10 unique codes but just saves last one on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i've tried many times with the code below to save 10 unique php generated codes to a column and i got the column updated with the last generated code only.
**what's wrong with this code?**

```
//GNRT_id
for($c=0;$c<10;$c++)
        {
$d_gnrt_id = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
$hex   = bin2hex($d_gnrt_id);

//add GNRT CDE to data
$q ="UPDATE mstfa_data SET d_gnrt_id = '$hex' where x_id > 1 "; 
$res = mysql_query($q);
echo "Done No: ".$c." AND CODE IS: ".$hex." and SQL_ERR=: ".mysql_error()."<br />";
}
```

**php Result was like this (no errors)**

```
Done No: 0 AND CODE IS: e899bff4566b49097f06916a14a31ce7c6194f50 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 1 AND CODE IS: 083edbe7bfca8186362911d1befad39694b17074 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 2 AND CODE IS: 1f612c052b5116dda2178d69d8e557c76303ab38 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 3 AND CODE IS: 51c33f7b74e6b279f123738054aba47fcc1666a2 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 4 AND CODE IS: d77d7b5321254d1f3c1ac401c56ff85445a6b6b0 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 5 AND CODE IS: 8e7e0cf691229e240c5ed71a9df28a8718ca7d04 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 6 AND CODE IS: 9c6c5dd99652ac3532d24480ed63f7317a93455d and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 7 AND CODE IS: b0d9559afad928042885267a3d5954f3a4c459b0 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 8 AND CODE IS: a56096c3e6dd9fd6a75196b3b8236a593590a228 and SQL_ERR=: 
Done No: 9 AND CODE IS: a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2 and SQL_ERR=:
```

**and MYSQL results in the selected column was like so**

```
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
 a185b07969d859912f4f0a18c25dea9db97c1dc2
```

what should i do?

Comment: *"php loop"* - what loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't you get just the last generated code? You're updating all the rows, not inserting new rows.

Comment: @Barmar , means what please explain more ?

Comment: You create a code, then update all the rows. Then you create another code and update all the rows. Why would they still have the first code if you updated all of them with the second code?

Comment: @Barmar Yes you're totally write , my Mysql Condition was wrong (id > 1) means all rows , so it was updating all rows for 10 times and this was the error , thanks so much . i've fixed due to this notification and i will put the answer now

Comment: Presumably this is for some sort of study into archaic coding practices?

Answer (score -1):

the MySql condition was logically wrong , it was updating all rows with (id >1) which means updating all rows * loop time ( 10 times ) so i fixed this code to be like this

```
$q = "select * from $tbl_1 where x_id >0";
$c_num = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($q));



        for($c=1;$c<$c_num;$c++)
        {

        //GNRT_id
            $d_gnrt_id = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
            $hex   = bin2hex($d_gnrt_id);

            //add GNRT CDE to data
            $q ="UPDATE mstfa_data SET d_gnrt_id = '$hex' where x_id = $c ";    
            $res = mysql_query($q);
            echo "Done No: ".$c." AND CODE IS: ".$hex." and SQL_ERR=: ".mysql_error()."<br />"; 

        }
```